# Missing Public API: visual-picking-tab.service.ts

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In the course of an EPD integration into our project, we have now encountered an error, which unfortunately cannot be fixed by us. The **"Visual-picking-tab.service.ts"** is not available in the public API and so we can not import it into a required constructor. We currently receive error messages which block us from continuing the integration.

Thank you for the quick fix

Addition:

The **VisualPickingProductFilterService** is also not public and is needed by us